# Reference article for k-mean clustering on multiple TIFF files

Tags: clustering

I have multiple TIFF files which represent different variables.
some of them are interpolated soil data some of them are satellite imagery,
some of them are DEM, Slope, TWI.
I used all of them together to run k-mean clustering to design management zones in an agricultural field. In short, my workflow was as follows,

*Preparing stack > Mask stack using a shapefile > Standardize the stacked tif files > Run PCA > Calculate Eigenvalue > Calculate factor score matrix > Use the factor score matrix as a basis for the k-mean clustering > Do the clustering using silhouette method > Provide a cluster map*.

Honestly, I took support from chatGPT to develop the workflow. But now, I am struggling to find a journal article that can be used as a reference for my workflow.

Comment: The best place to ask this question is [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net).